# is it possible to access more RAM beyond CPU limit of 64GB considering the motherboard limit is 128GB?

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, ramdisk

I got a CPU that can access up to 64GB.
The motherboard accepts up to 128GB.
I got 2x 16GB on slots 1 and 3 (same channel).

Now, I want to buy 1x 32GB, it will add up to 64GB and the CPU can access it.

But later, if I buy another 32GB, it would become 96GB the MOBO can access, but I know the CPU wont be able to access it all, only 64GB.

So, I wonder if there is some other way to let these extra 32GB be accessed in some way?
may be a RAM DRIVE?
or could it be made available to some other board on the PCIeX4 thru some BIOS config?
or some other config on the BIOS that could let that extra RAM be accessed in some other way?

If the BIOS could "detach/isolate" one RAM slot, to not be accessed directly by the CPU, so that slot could be reserved to work as a RAMDisk accessed direcly by the BIOS and some specific CHIP integrated on the motherboard, it could work I guess. Not merely a BIOS software patch would be required, but also a motherboard that supports doing that tweak I guess.

Any ideas?

PS.: I know I would have to buy another CPU to access 128GB. I am not asking for a PCIeX4 card where I could put the extra 32GB ram, or the old 2x 16GB ram, as the idea is about occupying the 4 RAM slots on the MOBO and keep available the PCI... and M2 etc slots.

Comment: If the CPU cannot access the memory then how do you expect a RAM drive which is a piece of software running on the CPU to access it? The memory controller is built in to the CPU, it is not a separate part of the system so *any* memory access is handled by the CPU.

Comment: “I am not asking for a PCIeX4 card where I could put the extra 32GB ram” - Good it does not exist, ok it actually does, on a z16 mainframe from IBM that is sold for starting at hundreds of thousands of dollars. Your system probably supports 32GB modules most newer hardware does

Comment: @Ramhound gigabyte fpga https://www.anandtech.com/Show/Index/1697?cPage=4&all=False&sort=0&page=5&slug=

Comment: @Mokubai the same way gibabyte fpga does, may be the bios could too I think

Comment: @AquariusPower - You completely miss understand the purpose of that 15 year old daughter board. It’s to use as a RAMDisk, it wouldn’t have been system memory, there is a reason that product was never popular

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Given the hardware you have, you cannot address the memory you want to address. This is a hardware limit, and you need to change the hardware to change the limit.

Comment: but if the BIOS could "detach/isolate" one RAM slot, to not be accessed directly by the CPU, so that slot could be reserved to work as a RAMDisk direcly by the BIOS and some specific CHIP on the motherboard, it could work I guess. Not merely a BIOS software patch would be required, but also a motherboard that supports doing that tweak I guess.

Comment: Are you a mainboard engineer or an OS designer? Yes? Then build that system. The PCs you buy on the shelf or build from components you can buy to run common software on do not function that way. What you're picturing will require custom hardware and custom software. It's theoretically possible, but is impossible given the "common PC hardware and software" limitations assumed here.